# Formula to establish specific dates 1 year apart

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm working on a formula to align with our business' invoicing policy. The rules are that, if an order is placed, the first invoice is generated same day.

```
=IF(OR(I90='2b - LookUp Values-UI'!K185,I90=TODAY()),"PASS","FAIL")
```

The above is sufficient for that requirement; however, I need to create another formula that will take the original invoice date into account and schedule the 2nd and 3rd invoices for exactly 1 and 2 years later. (e.g. If the initial invoice generates 2/15/2019, they Y2 Invoice will automatically generate 2/15/2020, and the Y3 will generate 2/15/2021)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand that `I90` holds your invoice date?

This formula will add a year to the date in `I90`.

`=DATE(YEAR(I90)+1,MONTH(I90),DAY(I90))`

This formula will add two years to the date in `I90`.

`=DATE(YEAR(I90)+2,MONTH(I90),DAY(I90))`

Answer (score 3):

Here’s an answer that is almost functionally equivalent to [Alex M’s](https://superuser.com/q/1405868/150988#1405911),
but less typing:

```
=EDATE(I90, 12)
```

The `12` is (obviously) a number of months. 
This handles leap year, but differently from Alex’s answer:

```
+--------------+---------------+---------------+
|  Input Data  | Alex's answer |   My answer   |
|   (“I90”)    |  (YEAR()+1…)  |    (EDATE)    |
+--------------+---------------+---------------+
|  2/27/2020   |   2/27/2021   |   2/27/2021   |
|  2/28/2020   |   2/28/2021   |   2/28/2021   |
|  2/29/2020   |   2/28/2021   |    3/1/2021   |
|   3/1/2020   |    3/1/2021   |    3/1/2021   |
|   3/2/2020   |    3/2/2021   |    3/2/2021   |
+--------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Apparently `EDATE` [has been in Excel since 2007.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edate-function-3c920eb2-6e66-44e7-a1f5-753ae47ee4f5)

Answer (score -1):

You can add to dates and today like so:

```
=Today()+365

=DATE(2019,2,14)+365
```

To account for leap years you can add only to the year with:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1)+2, MONTH(A1), DAY(A1))
```

Comment: This formula will lose a day every four years or so

Comment: @AlexM I saw your comment about not accounting for leap years but did not see that you had submitted an answer and it seems our independent research came up with the same/similar answers.  Thank you for the note of where my formula would not work, and I apologize if I stepped on your toes sir.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I retract the allegation (and have deleted my comment). I'll take the nearly identical answer as corroboration that I worked out the correct method, then. Cheers